# HTML how to fix <td> width after rotation?

Tags: html, html-table, rotation

I want to make the box size according to text.

**Code**

```html
•rotate { 
-moz-transform: rotate(90.0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(90.0deg ); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(90.0deg ); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
width:10px
}
</style> 
<title>Page Title</title>
</head> 
<body>
   <table id="t01" >
   <tr>
      <th width="90px">11-1</th>
      <th width="90px">11-2</th>
      <th width="90px">11-3</th>
      <th width="90px">11-4</th>
      <th width="90px">11-5</th>
      <th width="15px"></th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="center"› - </td> <td align="center"› - </td> <td align="center"› Pyccioin </td> 
      <td align="center" style="background-color:Grey;"> 01.13KyAbT </td>
      <td align="center" style="background-color:Grey;"> 01.13KyAbT </td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td rowspan="8" id.'rotate' width="10px">Douelienbum</td>
   </tr>
```

I have included the image in which my output is shown but I don't want this
**Problem image**

[image]

Comment: Please add code directly, do not link to images

Answer (score 0):

When the table cell is rotated you need to set `height` instead of `width`.

```
#rotate {height: 10px;}
```